# How to make a super method to cover four base methods with python?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

The code below is written by me, however I find the method is not suitable sometimes. I don't know how to make a good `super` method to cover four base selenium web-driver methods.

```
def keymouse(url, operation , elementxpath):
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.get(url)
    time.sleep(1)
    driver.maximize_window()
    time.sleep(1)
    operation_by = operation.split('.')[1]

    if operation_by == "context_click()":
        result = ActionChains(driver).context_click(driver.find_element_by_xpath(elementxpath)).perform()
    if operation_by == "double_click()":
        result = ActionChains(driver).double_click(driver.find_element_by_xpath(elementxpath)).perform()
    if operation_by == "drag_and_drop()":
        result = ActionChains(driver).drag_and_drop(driver.find_element_by_xpath(elementxpath), driver.find_element_by_xpath(elementxpath)).perform()
    if operation_by == "click_and_hold()":
        result = ActionChains(driver).click_and_hold(driver.find_element_by_xpath(elementxpath)).perform()
    else:
        time.sleep(3)
```

This is the instance to use the above method:

```
from method.key_mouse import *
#driver = webdriver.Chrome()

keymouse("https://www.baidu.com", "operation.context_click()", "//*[@id='kw']")
```

Answer (score 0):

A good way would be to use the [enum](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html) module.

```
from enum import Enum
# Create your desired operations
class KeyMouseOperation(Enum):
    CONTEXT_CLICK = 1
    DOUBLE_CLICK = 2
    DRAG_AND_DROP = 3
    CLICK_AND_HOLD = 4

from method.key_mouse import *
#driver = webdriver.Chrome()

keymouse("https://www.baidu.com", KeyMouseOperation.CONTEXT_CLICK, "//*[@id='kw']")

def keymouse(url, operation , elementxpath):
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.get(url)
    time.sleep(1)
    driver.maximize_window()
    time.sleep(1)

    if operation_by == KeyMouseOperation.CONTEXT_CLICK:
        result = ActionChains(driver).context_click(driver.find_element_by_xpath(elementxpath)).perform()
    if operation_by == KeyMouseOperation.DOUBLE_CLICK:
        result = ActionChains(driver).double_click(driver.find_element_by_xpath(elementxpath)).perform()
    if operation_by == KeyMouseOperation.DRAG_AND_DROP:
        result = ActionChains(driver).drag_and_drop(driver.find_element_by_xpath(elementxpath), driver.find_element_by_xpath(elementxpath)).perform()
    if operation_by == KeyMouseOperation.CLICK_AND_HOLD:
        result = ActionChains(driver).click_and_hold(driver.find_element_by_xpath(elementxpath)).perform()
    else:
        time.sleep(3)
```